# Retrieve a list of file resource thru Drive Api

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am using Drive api to retrieve the list of files from Google Drive using this Java Code:

---

```
Files.List request = services.files().list();
List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
do {
    try {
        FileList files = request.execute();
        System.out.println("getAlternateLink::"+files.getItems().get(0).getAlternateLink());
        result.addAll(files.getItems());
        request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.log(Level.WARNING, "An error occured: ", e);
        request.setPageToken(null);
    }
} while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
```

---

Using the **getAlternateLink** method, I got [this](https://docs.google.com/a/test.com/file/d/0IVwRm7safgdRV9RUzRRbms/edit?usp=drivesdk) url.

My question is how to write a code to get '/**spreadsheet**' location instead of '**/file**' in url. i.e -

https://docs.google.com/a/test.com/spreadsheet/d/0IVwRm7safgdRV9RUzRRbms/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I only see Parents: list method to get the parent folder id but not the actual location. This method specifies if the file is in root folder or in a subfolder. check this link : https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/list . Hope that information helps!

Answer (score 0):

You only get a /spreadsheet URL if the file is a Google Spreadsheet. If it is a general file or even a MS Excel file, you will get a /file URL.

You can limit your query to just Google Spreadsheets by using a mime_type filter for "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"